# How can I perform search & replace in a text file based on conditions?

Tags: macros, find-and-replace

I have a large text file (.bib) with lots of double entries for some fields. Essentially, the file is a `.bib`-file (more info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biber_%28LaTeX%29)) which has roughly 1000 entries. The content is structured like this:

```
@Article{Apak_2011_Financialriskmanagement,
Title                    = {Financial risk management in renewable energy sector: Comparative analysis between the European Union and Turkey},
Author                   = {Apak, Sudi and Atay, Erhan and Tuncer, Güngör},
Journal                  = {Procedia - Social and Behavioral Sciences},
Pages                    = {935--945},
Volume                   = {24},
Year                     = {2011},
Doi                      = {10.1016/j.sbspro.2011.09.013},
ISSN                     = {1877-0428},
}

@Incollection{Berger_1992_OutputMeasurementin,
Title                    = {Output Measurement in the Service Sectors},
Author                   = {Berger, Allen N. and Humphrey, David B.},
Crossref                 = {Griliches_1992_OutputMeasurementinb},
Pages                    = {245--300 book},
Year                     = {1992},
Publisher                = {University of Chicago Press},
Date                    = {1992-10-04},
Booktitle                = {Output Measurement in the Service Sectors},
Editor                   = {Griliches, Zvi and Berndt, Ernst R. and Bresnahan, Timothy F. and Manser, Marilyn}
}

@Book{Bogenstahl_2012_ManagementvonNetzwerken,
  Title                    = {Management von Netzwerken},
  Author                   = {Bogenstahl, Christoph},
  Publisher                = {Gabler},
  Date                     = {2012-01-01},
  ISBN                     = {978-3-8349-3572-4},
  Series                   = {Strategisches Kompetenz-Management}
}
```

You'll see that there is only `Year` defined for the first source. The second source however, has both `Year` and `Date` defined.

### EDIT: HINDSIGHT IS 20/20

I just noticed that I always need the `Year` field because I manage the whole file via [JabRef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JabRef). And for generating a bibtex-key, JabRef needs the `Year`-field. I mean I haven't found an option to generate the bibtex-key with the help of the `yyyy`-part of the `Date`-field so far, so I'll edit the conditions.

So, is there a way to do the following actions:

- If there is only `Date` defined for a source entry, copy the first 4 digits (yyyy) to `Year`.
- If there is only `Year` defined, copy the four digits to `Date`.
- If there is both `Date` and `Year` defined, do nothing.

### Now following are the old conditions, when I hadn't thought of JabRef's inner workings beforehand

Old conditions, still relevant if one would like to prepare the .bib-file for the use with biblatex and has a mixup of the `Date` and `Year`field in his file:

- If there is only `Date` defined for an source entry, do nothing.
- If there is both `Date` and `Year` defined, copy the content of the brackets for `Date` into the brackets for `Year`. The catch here is, `Date` *might* contain more information (by the format yyyy-mm-dd) than `Year`, so this is exactly why I am writing down these "conditions". Regardless of the contents of `Year`, `Date` is more important. Unless I made some errors while typing all the info in, the first 4 digits of `Date` should be equal to `Year` of course.
- If there is only `Year` defined, the term `Year` can be simply replaced with `Date`.

---

A few notes:

- If this info could be of any help in this case: I use Windows 7 and Xubuntu 14.04. I have Office 2010, if that could be used here... or I could gladly use some sort of tool on Xubuntu, I don't know.
- I checked already and apparently I can't use JabRef for this, it's a bit too complicated.

Comment: I have a few questions. 1. The @Incollection record seems to be a part of the first @Article record (I judge by the comma after the last entry in @Article and after the @Article itself). Should those two be treated independently? 2. You want `Date` to be copied to `Year`. What if the date contains more than just a year? Should month and day of month be copied too?

Comment: @AtomHeartFather Sorry about that comma, that was a little error on my part. I deleted it. Yes they should be treated independently. About your 2nd question, see op. Basically, regardless of the contents of `Year`, `Date` is more important. Unless I made some errors while typing all the info in, the first 4 digits of `Date` should be equal to `Year` of course. :)

Comment: Just posted the answer, but I see you've changed some of the requirements... So the answer is not valid anymore (I am working on it now)

Comment: @AtomHeartFather Your reply is still good for those who do not use JabRef and want to the .bib-files for the use with biblatex. I'll edit the old requirements into the op.

Answer (score 2):

I'd throw perl at this problem. http://search.cpan.org/~ambs/Text-BibTeX-0.70/lib/Text/BibTeX.pm should help. Something like:

```
use Text::BibTeX;

$bibfile = new Text::BibTeX::File "foo.bib";
$newfile = new Text::BibTeX::File ">newfoo.bib";

while ($entry = new Text::BibTeX::Entry $bibfile) {
    next unless $entry->parse_ok;

    if ($has_year = $entry->exists ('year')) {
        $year = $entry->get('year');
    }
    if ($has_date = $entry->exists ('date')) {
        $date = $entry->get('date');
    }
    if ($has_year and ! $has_date) {
        $entry->set('date', $year);
    }
    if ($has_date and ! $has_year) {
        $entry->set('year', substr($date, 0, 4));
    }
    $entry->write ($newfile);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** This solution is for the original set of requirements. It would need to be updated to work with the current version. And also, the `perl` based answer is much cleaner anyway :-)

If you don't mind creating some temporary files, this could be a starting point:
Copy that into a file and set the executable flag (`chmod +x file`)

```
#!/bin/bash
INFILE=$1

# split the file first
awk '/^@/{x="tmp__"++i}{print > x;}' $INFILE

# process individual files
for file in tmp__* ; do 
    DATE=$(grep "^[[:space:]]*Date" $file | sed "s/.*{\(.*\)}.*/\1/g")
    YEAR=$(grep "^[[:space:]]*Year" $file | sed "s/.*{\(.*\)}.*/\1/g")

    # Both year and date. Substitute year with date
    if [[ -n "$DATE" && -n "$YEAR" ]] ; then
        sed -i "s/\(^[[:space:]]*Year.*\)${YEAR}\(.*\)/\1${DATE}\2/g" $file
    fi

    # Only year
    if [[ -z "$DATE" && -n "$YEAR" ]] ; then
        sed -i "s/\(^[[:space:]]*\)Year/\1Date/g" $file
    fi
done

# concatenate the files back
cat tmp__* > out.bib
rm -f tmp__*
```

What the script does is:

- Takes one parameter - the input file name
- Splits the file into multiple temporary files, each of them containing only a single record
- iterates over the files and processes them individually according to your instructions (provided that I understood them well, that is - see below)
- concatenates the processed files into out.bib
- removes the temporary files.

The script does not modify the original input file, so it should be pretty safe.

I am still not completely clear about your requirements, so if you give it a go and find some cases where it does not do what you expect - feel free to let me know and I will try to improve it.